# Edit native android app

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, sms, editing

How can i edit  the native text app on android 6.0 from my phone?

I have a Wiko U Feel rooted with TWRP.

Is there a Xposed Module i can use?

ty

Comment: What do you mean by "edit"? Do you want to theme it, change some resources (literally "edit") inside, or replace the app altogether?

Comment: Nadav's suggestion will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the apk for the app you want to use.

Use ApkTool to edit resources or change the code

recompile,sign and install.